# Java - Как сделать задержку, при которой изменения можно увидеть наглядно?

Tags: java, android

Как сделать задержку, которую можно будет увидеть?
Мне необходимо передвигать seekbar автоматически при загрузке активити, и необходимо видеть процесс передвижения. Пробовал:

```
for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
    try {
        Thread.sleep(600);
        seekBar.setProgress(i+7);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

И сам процесс передвижения перепрыгивает, то есть он выполняется, но не видно процесса.

Comment: `for(int i = 0; i < 200; i++)
{
    try {
        Thread.sleep(50);
        seekBar.setProgress(i+0.35);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}` (короче говоря, просто увеличить количество шагов) //скорее всего есть готовые решения и это костыль

Comment: Вы блокируете UI-поток? У меня для вас плохие новости.

Comment: Согласен, с тем, что в это время UI-поток блокируется, поэтому я и спрашиваю как выполнить или с помощью чего? Возможно создать некоторый второй процесс?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Как-то так:

```
    new Thread() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(600);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        seekBar.setProgress(i + 7);                    
                    }
                });
            }
        }
    }.start();
```

Компилируемость кода не гарантируется, еще надо видимость переменных разрулить, но идея должна быть понятна.

Comment: Нужно объявить за границами класса:
    private static SeekBar seekBar;
    private static int i = 0;
И в конструкторе проинициализировать seekBar и всё работает.

Comment: static SeekBar это плохая идея, могут быть утечки контекста.

Comment: Переменную цикла тоже не обязательно выносить. `seekBar.setProgress(seekBar.getProgress() + 7);` как вариант.

Comment: а как лучше объявить SeekBar, если static - плохой вариант?

Comment: Стандартно, как переменная обьекта активити или фрагмента.